# Print an array in the form of a table with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array and my goal is to print the code in such a way that it puts out the following:

[image: Output Table]

How can I do that?

Comment: ... what does your array look like? what have tried so far?

Comment: So that each and every reader who prepares an answer doesn't have to construct the same object containing input data, please edit to provide it, so they can just copy and paste. For example, `arr = [{date: "2014-12-01", from: "Ferdous", subject: "Homework this week"}, {date: "2014-12-01", from: "Dajana", subject: "Keep on coding! :)"}, {date: 2014-12-02, from: "Madonna", subject: "Re: Homework this week"}]`.

Comment: you need to provide some more info on your environment (is it a rails project? is this an `ActiveRecord` table? etc) and some things about your code (eg a sample of the relevant class) and the attempts you 've made so far.

Comment: Might take a look at the `hirb` gem https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb

Comment: You really should accept the below answer. It is the right answer!

Answer (score 31):

I imagine there are lots of gems available for doing this, but if you want to roll-your-own, you could do it like this, in a fairly general way:

Your input is comprised of column labels:

```
col_labels = { date: "Date", from: "From", subject: "Subject" }
```

and the data for the rows:

```
arr = [{date: "2014-12-01", from: "Ferdous", subject: "Homework this week"},
       {date: "2014-12-01", from: "Dajana", subject: "Keep on coding! :)"},
       {date: "2014-12-02", from: "Ariane", subject: "Re: Homework this week"}]
```

where `col_labels` and the elements of `arr` have the same keys.

From this point on, the code is general.  First construct a hash `@columns` (which I've made an instance variable for convenience).

```
@columns = col_labels.each_with_object({}) { |(col,label),h|
  h[col] = { label: label,
             width: [arr.map { |g| g[col].size }.max, label.size].max } }
  # => {:date=>    {:label=>"Date",    :width=>10},
  #     :from=>    {:label=>"From",    :width=>7},
  #     :subject=> {:label=>"Subject", :width=>22}}

def write_header
  puts "| #{ @columns.map { |_,g| g[:label].ljust(g[:width]) }.join(' | ') } |"
end

def write_divider
  puts "+-#{ @columns.map { |_,g| "-"*g[:width] }.join("-+-") }-+"
end

def write_line(h)
  str = h.keys.map { |k| h[k].ljust(@columns[k][:width]) }.join(" | ")
  puts "| #{str} |"
end
```

```
write_divider
write_header
write_divider
arr.each { |h| write_line(h) }
write_divider

+------------+---------+------------------------+
| Date       | From    | Subject                |
+------------+---------+------------------------+
| 2014-12-01 | Ferdous | Homework this week     |
| 2014-12-01 | Dajana  | Keep on coding! :)     |
| 2014-12-02 | Ariane  | Re: Homework this week |
+------------+---------+------------------------+
```

If you want to reverse the display and make it a bit larger, like yours, first execute:

```
$_!.reverse
$_@ += 4
```

[image: Output Table]

Comment: Giant answer.. You made Postgresql DB like output ... Congratulations...+1

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is with the `table_print` gem: http://tableprintgem.com

For example, using the array from the other answer,

```rb
your_array = [
  {date: "2014-12-01", from: "Ferdous", subject: "Homework this week"},
  {date: "2014-12-01", from: "Dajana", subject: "Keep on coding! :)"},
  {date: "2014-12-02", from: "Ariane", subject: "Re: Homework this week"},
]
tp your_array
```

you would get the following result:

```markdown
DATE       | FROM    | SUBJECT
-----------|---------|-----------------------
2014-12-01 | Ferdous | Homework this week
2014-12-01 | Dajana  | Keep on coding! :)
2014-12-02 | Ariane  | Re: Homework this week
```

You can also specify the columns you want to include (as strings or symbols):

```rb
tp your_array, "subject", :from
```

This is very useful when your array is from an ActiveRecord query, and displaying every single column would make the output unreadable:

```rb
tp User.all, :full_name, :e-mail_address
```

You can even access related models:

```rb
tp User.all, :full_name, "posts.title"
```